# How to install executable latex using tlmgr?

Tags: texlive, ubuntu, tlmgr, texlive-2018

OS: Ubuntu 18

If one decides to use `install-tl` to install only the most minimal `scheme` , then how can one install the executable `latex` ? Apparently doing `tlmgr install latex` is not enough, because when running `latex` on the terminal, it shows

`latex command not found` .

So, how can one install `latex` using only tlmgr ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the terminal run `apt-cache show texlive-latex-base` . The package `texlive-latex-base` is the one apt-get would install to install `latex`. From here, you can deduce that the command you need to run to install latex is:

`tlmgr install latex latex-bin`.